# Java document generation tool that does not use bands

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, ireport, documentation-generation

I am searching for a Java document generation tool that does not use a band approach like Jasper Reports does. I am trying to create a multi-page document (similar to what a contract would look like) that may contain graphs and paragraphs that may extend to more than one page. It also needs to be able to mail merge and do sub-reports. All of the tools that I have seen use the Jasper Reporting Engine which from my understanding, is more of a reporting tool and will not do what I want. I am not opposed to paid tools. Thanks a lot in advance for any help or comments that you are able to provide.

Comment: Band can fulfill all your wishes what ever you want.

Comment: I was under the impression that once you create a band it will be included on all pages. So in cases where a paragraph runs on to another page, it will be separated by a header for example. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Every band has its own beauty. If you are writing something in header it will show at every page at start up. Go and study ireport .

Comment: The trick is to put subreports in your main report's bands, the subreports themselves can have different designs (chart/table/text...)

Answer (score 0):

***No answer***

- The **.odt** or **.docx** format seems nice enough (zip with embedded XML, content and layout separable).
- The **HTML 5** format knows page breaks and seems easier to program (though PDF generation?).
- The **mark down** format (as used here in StackOverflow editing) is also easy to handle.
- **Docbook(x)** (XML) and **TeX** (superb results) would round the listing of formats.

I am not aware of any generation tools. Jasper Reports, though PITA sometimes, pulls the data from generalized data sources. XSLT needs a (difficult) kind of programming too.

My best tip would be to try a **wiki** system with PDF generation.

Comment: I've not heard of that type of system before. I will check some out. Does anyone else have input on this?

Comment: The wiki of Wikipedia offers PDF. At least the HTML is quite versatile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try BIRT report http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ or
Pentaho http://www.pentaho.com/ they have a slightly different approaches.
So far Jasper report is cool maybe a little learning of JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide book could solve your problem